# Control Arduino via Wifi directly?

Tags: wifi

I want to build an arduino-based RC Tank, which should be controlled with a notebook or smartphone (Android). Bluetooth would be an easy solution, but the range is a bit short for a RC Vehicle, so I want to controll it via WIFI. I found a ton of examples and tutorials on how to do that but all of them reqire a router which both the arduino and the Smartphone are connected to. Any idea on how to directly control an Arduino with an smartphone via WIFI?

Comment: you could make an ad-hoc network with your computer and connect straight to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer/tablet/phone can act as a WiFi hotspot, you could use that to avoid the router. Many smartphones have that capability, as do many notebooks (as geometrikal mentioned, it's usually referred to as an 'ad-hoc' network on PCs). Create the network (or turn on hotspot capability), and connect to the network you created from your Arduino.